# Setting Silverlight DataGrid to just throw an exception when binding field does not exist

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, datagrid, binding

I just <s>wasted</s> invested a good chunk of time trying to determine why a specific datagrid among many was showing shrunken rows with no text. After many trial and errors attempts to figure out what made this grid special, I finally found that the class used for the row items was marked private.

That is a perfectly good reason, but I would have prefered to have been able to narrow it down to a binding issue (and if possible a "field is not accessable due to protection level" type message) much sooner then it took to sysmatically disassemble the entire convoluted process it took to get data into and configure that grid. Ideally I shouldn't have had to see the wrong behavoir in the first place, an error should have occured immediately when a column attempted to read from a field that it could not.

All my datagrids inherit from a custom base class in order for some global standards to be applied - if there anything I can do in my CustomDataGrid class to cause an exception to be thrown whenever a columns binding expression fails, such as if the class/property is private or the property name has been mispelled in the binding expression? (This is different from binding validation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always keep an eye out on debug output window when dealing with SL/WPF databinding.  The framework(s) are actually pretty good at generating messages about databinding problems that include specific details about what fields it failed to bind on or what have you.

This doesn't exactly answer your original question, but it helped me sort through binding issues quite a bit once I realized there was good info being thrown into there.